# Construct object with highest ID + 1

Tags: java, lombok

I want to make a counter for the ID, and construct a new Person object with that ID.

**My lombok class:**

```
package nl.SBDeveloper.Persons.Lombok;

import lombok.Data;

@Data 
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

**My code:**

```
Person person = new Person();
```

What is the best way to create this?

Comment: Even using Lombok's `@Data`, you can still implement your own constructor. Just do that and increment some static `next_id` field.

Comment: Actually, that's not really clear: Do you want to get the max ID used and then pass that to the constructor, or should the constructor handle this itself?

Comment: I would personally avoid static field, since you will need syncronization for the increment. Anyway, u can write a method in a class called maybe "PersonCounter" or something like that that takes in input your list of person and get the highest id. If otherwise the purpose is to create person with an ID that is incremental (hiding that to the caller of new) then maybe the private static field with syncronized increment and set inside the constructor as suggested by tobias is a way to go. Otherwise u can think about a factory class that manage Person construction...it depends on your needs

Comment: Seems completely unrelated to Lombok. I've edited your question to remove it

Answer (score 4):

Define a static field. @Data creates a constructor using only the required arguments. ID is not required since it's already assigned, so you get a constructor which just takes a name.

```
@Data
public class Person {
    private static final AtomicInteger currentId = new AtomicInteger();    

    private final int id = currentId.incrementAndGet();
    private final String name;
}
```

Usage:

```
Person bob = new Person("Bob");
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your data class:

```
public class Person {
  private int id;
  private String name;

  Person(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }
}
```

You can keep track of how many Person objects you create by defining a PeopleFactory object, and giving it a static `personCount` field. To make sure this counter is thread-safe, you would need to synchronize the field, or synchronize the method in charge of Person creation.

```
public class PersonFactory {
  private static int personCount = 0;

  public PersonFactory() {
  }

  public synchronized Person getPerson(String name) {
    personCount++;
    return new Person(personCount, name);
  }
}
```

Testing our implementation:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PersonFactory personFactory = new PersonFactory();
    Person bill = personFactory.getPerson("Bill");
    System.out.println("ID: " + bill.getId() + ", Name: " + bill.getName());
  }
}
```

> > ID: 1, Name: Bill